# Get css class attribute value in gwt?

Tags: gwt

I have a css class declared:

```css
gwt-Label {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Is there a way I can query the value of font-size at runtime? Something like:

```java
public void foo() {
    CssFoo css = new CssFoo("gwt-Label");
    float fontSize = css.getAttribute("font-size");
    println("Your font size is: " + fontSize);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a piece of JSNI code to get the computedValue, or a better option is to use [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/).

```
 import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;
 ...

 // the second parameter set to true means: return the real computed value
 double size = $(my_widget).cur("font-size", true);
```

If you are interested on doing it with js you could do something like this (it should work in modern browsers)

```
 private static final double getPropertyValue(Element elem, String prop) /*-{
   return $wnd.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(prop);
 }-*/
```

But I would go with gquery which works with all browsers, and do more like workaround for hidden elements, not-camelized properties etc.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

The [Style class](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Style.html) Constructor is *invisible* in GWT.So you cant create an Object of That.

But you can get the Style object on an Element

ex:

```
 TextBox textbox= new TextBox();
 Style style = textbox.getElement().getStyle();
 String fontSize = style.getFontSize();
```

or  by

```
String attribute = textbox.getElement().getAttribute("fontSize");//camelcase
```

or

```
String styleAttribute = DOM.getStyleAttribute(textbox.getElement(), "fontSize");
```

Comment: just a note: `getStyleAttribute` does not return the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/computed_value)  (values which could be set in css sheets, or initial) but values set to the property via js or the `style='...'` attribute.

Comment: Thankyou verymuch @Manolo.I did'nt aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently, its solved in GWT simply with;

fontSize = ComputedStyle .getStyleProperty(this.getElement(), "fontSize");

This will get the computed value that your class has previously supplied to it.